# Swift adding to end of array

Tags: swift

I know that Array has the `append(_:)` method, but this mutates the original array.

Why doesn't Array also implement `appending(_:)` which would return a new array with that element appended? I've implemented this a few times now, but am wondering if there is a reason why it doesn't already exist?

(My only guess would be that this is to do with efficiency - if you used this method in a loop you would be copying your array multiple times?)

Comment: Why a separate method if you can write `let newArray = oldArray + [element]` ?

Comment: I've assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that `let newArray = oldArray + element` would be more efficient that making a temporary array just to contain element?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extension of Array do to this :

```
extension Array{
    func appending(_ element:Element) -> Array<Element>{
        var result = self
        result.append(element)
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it can be done - I'm more interested in why it hasn't been done already :)

Comment: (I've clarified my question to remove ambiguity about what I'm asking)

Comment: May be like you said is for efficiency reasons. I think if you make an Unit test to measure performance of a method that makes a loop of this extension and another UT with a method in witch you use the standard append method you will see the difference. You canals use Instruments to measure memory allocation and CPU performance.

Answer (score 0):

What are we discussing?

Starting from 'append' documentation:

> ```
> /// Append `newElement` to the Array.
> ///
> /// - Complexity: Amortized O(1) unless `self`'s storage is shared with another live array; O(`count`) if `self` does not wrap a bridged
> ```
>
> `NSArray`; otherwise the efficiency is unspecified..
>       public mutating func append(newElement: Element)

You need to have knowledge about pointer and smart pointer.

**M** elements

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
```

Is a simple array.

If you append **N** elements, complexity will be **O(N)**

```
func addElements() {
    for elment in [4, 5, 6] {
        a.append(element)
    }
}
```

If you create a new array starting from **a**:

```
var b = a
```

At run time **b** points to **a**, so if you execute again `addElements` complexity will be **O(M)** in order to copy original array plus **O(N)** in order to add N elements.

Why documentation says?

> "otherwise the efficiency is unspecified.."

Because in this example we have a simple array of integer, but the behaviour of copying array of custom objects is unpredictable.